# Most efficient way of passing values from OGRGeometry to ModelField in geodjango

Tags: shapefile, convert, geodjango

I am writing a custom parser that maps shapefile data to a geodjango model in a Django 1.6 project. To read the shapefile I use the [`DataSource`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/#django.contrib.gis.gdal.DataSource) object from `django.contrib.gis.gdal`, which provides access to the shapefile data through [`OGRGeometry`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/#django.contrib.gis.gdal.OGRGeomType) objects.

In my loop I want to map the geometries into my model as follows

```
dt = DataSource('path/to/my/shapefile')
lyr = dt[0]
for feat in lyr:
    MyModel.objects.create(
        geom = feat.geom.FOO
    )
```

My question is, what is the most efficient conversion for `FOO` in that loop?

The feature geometry can be extracted in several ways, for instance

[wkt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/#django.contrib.gis.gdal.OGRGeometry.wkt), [wkb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/#django.contrib.gis.gdal.OGRGeometry.wkb), [hex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/#django.contrib.gis.gdal.OGRGeometry.hex), etc.